# Compile-time PHP errors in VSCode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Has anyone configured VS Code to show syntax/semantic errors in PHP development? Coming from full Visual Studio/C# world, I really miss this thing a lot. Currently I actually have to call my PHP function using a client, only to get a HTTP 500 error and then check server logs to see what went wrong. This is a huge pain. Going through all of this only to find for example that I didn't import a require namespace, is so frustrating.

I understand that PHP by design cannot detect all kinds of errors like C# at *compile time* (so to speak), but detecting functions that do not exist or not passing required parameters should be easy to catch.

Is there a plug-in or setting in VS Code that could handle syntax/semantic error in PHP code? I'm using Laravel on the server-side, if that matters.

Comment: I have PHP IntelliSense and PHP Debug extensions. The first one will show syntax errors, and, with XDebug, you can debug your application like in C#.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte: I too have both of them installed. But it doesn't tell me if my code is missing a namespace import, which is more of a semantic error than syntax. It also doesn't tell me if I have missed a parameter. It even misses Object.Method does not exist thing. All these are caught only in the logs. XDebug on the other hand is a debug-time helper. Of course it is a great tool and helps me a lot, but it is not meant to catch semantic problems.

Comment: You can try to use psalm (psalm.dev) and its extension to VSCode. I don't use it but you can give a try.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I found something. I uninstalled PHP Intellisense extension this morning and installed [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) and all seems to be far better. Not only that the syntax and semantic errors are highlighted, it automatically injects required namespaces too. And if that were not enough, `Go To Definition` (F12) command has started working correctly all of a suden. :)

Must-have extension for any PHP work in VSCode I'd say.